# Mac with NO internal hard Drive/brokenEfi and ubuntu

Tags: uefi, mac

a few years ago I got an old Mac (2009 version). I tried to fix it but I gave up after days of workimg.

Last week i tried it once again. It seems that there is no (totally broken, I dont know) Hardd Dive, the EFI Mode doesnt work really (Mouse and keyboard dont work, the GUI looks really strange, difficult to describe, also a MacOS-CD couldn help at all!) 
I came trough with a Ubuntu CD and installed it on my external Hard Drive. 
But now I have some Problems, where I need our wisdom!

1. Because EFI seems to be broken I have to start with the UbuntuCD and start from there the installed ubuntu on the external Hard Drive. When i try ALT or something else. EFI is totally unable to let me boot from my external (wired graphics and no control over keyboard etc)
   Is there a way to install EFI new or get a way around it? (like EFI on the external?)
2. From what I understand EFI controls the fans, which makes sense, because they are also broken. They are ALWAYS on fullspeed even when i just started the MAc,even  in EFI, in Ubuntu, in LiveCD...
   How can I fix this? Ok the Mac seems to get hot but it shouldnt listen like an Airplane...

Thx for your amazing work here

PS: 
Ubuntu 14.04 lts

Mac : http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.66-24-inch-aluminum-early-2009-specs.html

Comment: A 2009 mac with fans at a proper speed does sound like a airplane ;) Can you take a picture of the strange looking GUI? You can post to imigur and then paste a link, we can then edit it into the question for you.

Comment: Sorry I have pictures on my laptop I will send them tomorrow.. It looks white with blury stuff on it and sometimes the pictures of the HardDrive/MacOSCD are vertical sorted sometimes just overlaying and atm he just shows a really strange symbol for trying to conect to the net.. I know how how it should look correctly :P Well with the fans: it seems like the fans are constant at the same speed, so they dont regulate down when the Mac does a cold start, they just stay ALWAYS at the same level

Comment: Hey I tried it yesterdaywith the MacOSX-CD, first it showed the correct sysmbol of the blinking globus (but there was also times where there were graphical errors) and after a long time it stardet the CD were it looked like this... no installation possible.. 
http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/img2399vius9ymc61.jpg

Comment: Oh, something hardware wise is broken then...

Comment: nope on ubuntu everything seems to be working.. exept Fans are on constant speed

Comment: no starting ubuntu with the liveCD is apain in the ass, because I have to start 3 times till it works :D also this Mac is for my girlfriend, so it has to be superuserfriendly if you know what I mean :D I think of this options:

1/ Repairing/upgrading EFI without MacOS just in Ubuntu

2/ Chancing The bootorder with rEFIt or installing it (on Ubuntu)

This is where I need help atm, and also thx for your time=)
btw, am I right when I asume that EFI is on the motherboard installed?